# Search Layout is not displayed for an object in search layout

Tags: search-layout

Created an object and I need to add a search layout for this object. But the search layout option itself is not visible for this object.

I created some more object but there is no issue with other objects.

Please help how can I add search layout here?

Comment: I think the presence of a tab that is at least available or visible to required to edit the search layouts.

Comment: Only the Custom Objects that have their own tab are included in search results.

Comment: Yes, the object I have created is custom object only.

Comment: I have tested by creating 2 custom objects:    1. allowed tab to be created and it has search layout.    2. Didn't launched tab and search layout is not available.

Comment: So I guess creating a tab will resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, but I do not need to create a tab for this custom object as per my use case. That's why I need to know is there any other workaround to get this option visible under my custom object?

Answer (score 9):

It can be enabled by opening the Object in Edit mode and Tick the checkbox that says `Allow Search`

Go to this link for step by step approach :

http://www.srinivas4sfdc.com/2016/01/how-to-enable-search-layout-section-for.html

As we already know that once you have created any new custom object ,in the custom object detail page you will be seeing an section called Search Layout.But from Winter 16 releases for newly created objects you might not be able see the Search layouts section. because from winter 16 for newly created objects Search Layout Section will not be enabled automatically.Why is it?

Allow Search Feature

1. Salesforce has introduced a new feature in winter 16 called "Allow Search "to disable or enable Search layout for a particular custom object
2. By using this feature you can improve the performance of global search/Side search by excluding unnecessary custom objects from search results
3. At the time of custom object creation you need to choose whether you want to enable or not.
4. If you want enable or disable follow below steps

   - Goto Setup--->Objects--->Custom Objects
   - Open the custom object for which you want to enable
   - Goto Search Status and select allow search to enable or deselect to disable
   - Go and observe the  Search Layouts section in object detail page

[image]

Comment: Since [Summer 22 Search Layout is called List View Button Layout](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_search_list_view_button_layout.htm&release=238&type=5) in Lightning Experience. If the button is missing, then search is off.

Answer (score 1):

If Tab is not added for the custom object, then also the search layout Profile wise doesn't show. Add Tab by going through setup and search tabs.