# Search Result missing from search layouts

Tags: administration, configuration, search, page-layout, search-layout

[image]
[image]
In my sandbox, I've made some edits to the search result search layout in lightning for a custom object.

In another org, which is a production org, I'm trying to make those same changes, but there is no search result layout in the search layout section.

Does anybody know what could cause this discrepancy to happen? I've checked some other custom objects and they have the search result layout.

Thanks!

Comment: possible that your sandbox is using summer 17, while your production is still using spring? maybe there have been changes, have you read the release notes?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120280/search-layout-is-not-displayed-for-an-object-in-search-layout.  see if this can help you !!

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot og both the cases?

Comment: @NitishSinghal I've added some screenshots

Comment: @amidstCloud I've already made sure that option is selected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the object in the org missing search results have a tab created ?

Search and tabs are connected, if you do not have a tab for the object/ the user does not have access to the tab the search results/ filters may not be available for the object.

Finally Vote for this idea if you want this feature changed:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kS4eAAE&tab=v

Comment: Turns out it needs a tab to be created! I don't even know where I would've found this answer if I hadn't posted on here, not intuitive at all.

Comment: That's the power of SFSE, united we stand and help each other :D