# Salesforce Lightning - Search layout no Profile or Columns Displayed

Tags: lightning, community, search-layout

On one of my objects under Search Layout there is nothing showing under Profiles or Columns Displayed. IN classic I have search layout setup correctly but in Lightning nothing shows other than Name. I was going to adjust this under Search Layouts but nothing is displaying.

[image]

Comment: Custom or standard object?

Comment: Custom Object Not standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kS4eAAE&tab=v

[Search Result missing from search layouts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177696/search-result-missing-from-search-layouts)

Do you have a tab created for this custom object? It seems based on other answers and that idea, that there's a link between tab and search layouts which may explain why you see none for this custom object.

Comment: That is awful but seems to be correct. Thanks